# Today, yesterday, and day before yesterday revenue

Tags: tableau-api

I got dimension:

- date
- user id
- user name (a user name can have multiple user id's)

Measures:

- revenue_today

I want for every user name, his user id's, with today's revenue, yesterday's revenue, and day before yesterday's revenue. I have problems with showing yesterday's and day before yesterday's revenue. So far I've tried this for yesterday:

```
IF DATEDIFF('day',[Date)], TODAY()) = - 1 THEN [revenue_today] END
```

However, when I drag into a table it doesn't show any value. I also tried this:

```
if [Date] = TODAY() - 1 then [revenue_today] END
```

I have set Date in filter to Relative Dates -> Today.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you just have to switch off date filter, because it filters all the data for yesterday before revenue calculation